# Do there exist nontrivial bi-invariant differential forms on $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

More specifically, $1$-forms and/or $2$-forms.

Since $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not compact the usual averaging trick doesn't work.

If the answer is no, do there exist nontrivial Ad-invariant forms on $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: It does have a two-sided Haar measure... so there'd be a $3$-form...

Comment: Hint: Start by identifying forms on the Lie algebra invariant under the adjoint action if the group. Can you find any? Why not?